# When using Microsoft Access DSNs do I simply replace the database connection string with the path of the DSN?

Tags: ms-access, shared-hosting, dsn

I have inherited a web application with an Access backend (yes I know).

I need to get this thing deployed asap to a shared hosting provider. Unfortunately, it's not as easy as I imagined as hosts tend to lock down access to Access databases (AFAICT).

I have a shared account with GoDaddy - I have enabled Access database use, and created a DSN.

The application has references to the database connection string littered throughout it. Is using DSNs simply a matter of changing the connection string to be the path of the DSNs?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I did this, but you should just be able to change the connection string to DSN=MYDSNNAme

I would try it locally first though.

Obviously if you are going to go to this trouble, replace each occurance with a variable, so if you need to do it again it will be easier :)